# Segue implementation via code

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am a newbie in IOS. I am creating an Authorization Scene in a Storyboard. It consists  of **textFields** (username, password) and **buttons** (Log In, Sign Up). When login and password are correct, **UIAlertView** is displayed with text "Success". After this, MainScene should be displayed.   But I can't create a segue in Interface Builder.   How can I implement it via code?

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder or Storyboard?

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv I am using Storyboard.

Comment: Yas Kuraishi has already given right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

1. Create a Segue from your source ViewController (not control) to the destination ViewController.
2. Give Segue a name on the Interface Builder storyboard file.
3. Perform Segue programmatically: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:nil];`

> **Note:** To create Segue from a ViewController, hold control down and
>   drag source ViewController instead of a control as you would normally
>   do, to the destination controller.