# Do segues work only with nav controllers?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I've tried to make a segue using the storyboard from one ViewController to another, but it has thrown an exception.

Do segues only work with NavigationControllers?  It worked when I've tried it that way.

Comment: What exception ?? may be the way you are using seague is wrong. Check the identifier if it matches with what your have specified in your storybard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `Segue` is created from one `ViewController` to another then you need to perform it programmatically as only visual elements such as views can respond to user events so without user interaction there is no way for `ViewController` to know when to perform a `Segue`.

Here is how you can do it programmatically.

1. Set `Segue` identifier in the Interface Builder.
2. Call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:nil];` in response to an event, i.e. button's `TouchUpInside` to perform it.

> *This post has little bit more info:*
>   [Segue implementation via code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833184/segue-implementation-via-code/18833483#18833483)

**NOTE:** If you are not using `NavigationController` then you can't use Push `Segue` transition since that requires a `NavigationController`. You can still use `Modal` transition type or `Custom` if you want to come up with your own transition.

Answer (score 0):

if you have your ViewControllers embedded in a `UINavigationController` using Storyboard from `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerB` :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) 
    {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = (ViewControllerB *)navController.topViewController;

        // Pass data (for example a NSString object)
        viewControllerB.aString = myString;
    }
}
```